# Python API parse JSON request error

Tags: python

Here is my python script. It sends a HTTP request to request music chart data from deezer. It should then print the album names.

```
import requests
import json
import time

json_txt = requests.get('http://api.deezer.com/chart')

parsed_json = json.loads(json_txt)

print(json_txt.text['album'])

print "Success!"
```

However, I am confused why I get the following response:

```
Success!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deezer_get+parse.py", line 9, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_txt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Please could somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `json_txt` is not a string; it's a response object. You need to parse its subelement.

```
parsed_json = json.loads(json_txt.text)
print parsed_json['album']
```